# Word automation - CopyFormat in loop = slow

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-automation

I'm trying to copy / paste the formatting of a Field in Word. (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word)

My goal is to copy the formatting, update the field en paste the formatting to apply it on the new content. (in my test code, the part of updating and pasting is left out)

I've noticed that this becomes very slow in a large loop.
I have +- 5000 fields in my Word document. After +-500 iterations, it takes up to 1.2 seconds to execute one iteration (just for the code at the bottom of this post). After it reaches 1.2 seconds, the duration no longer increases (perhaps has something to do with a buffer.)

Can anyone give me a solution to improve the speed?

```
    foreach (Field o in m_doc.Fields)
    {
      if (o.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldRef)
      {
        o.Select();
        Range r = o.Result;
        r.Select();
        m_doc.Application.Selection.CopyFormat();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm grasping at straws a bit, here, however...

1. You can certainly speed things up a bit by leaving out o.Select(); It's not necessary and every SELECT call you make will noticeably affect performance.
2. Slowness is a known issue in foreach loops - it has to do with the way the API works with the document. As best I can recall, it more or less tends to start at the beginning and count forward in each loop. A "for" loop using an index counter tends to be faster. And in some cases a "for" loop that cylces BACKWARDS can even be more efficient.